# How to update meta tags in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a single page application in react.js, so what is the best way to update meta tags on page transitions or browser back/forward?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've used [react-document-meta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta) in an older project.

Just define your meta values

```
const meta = {
    title: 'Some Meta Title',
    description: 'I am a description, and I can create multiple tags',
    canonical: 'http://example.com/path/to/page',
    meta: {
        charset: 'utf-8',
        name: {
            keywords: 'react,meta,document,html,tags'
        }
    }
```

and place a

```
<DocumentMeta {...meta} />
```

in the return

Comment: will tags change with the page transitions or only for the landing page?

Comment: How is your application structured? Do you have multiple components or just one which gets changed while transitioning?

Comment: 2 components would change, rest remain same.

Comment: Also I am seeing this module is no longer active https://github.com/skevy/react-document-meta . Is the one mentioned in link and one mentioned by you the same?

Comment: yes you're right. didn't saw that but the react-helmet should work fine. you would have to define a set for all your transitions and set  the attribs accordingly before rendering

Comment: If i share any content on social media, will this work as expected, like in terms of og-url, twitter-url etc.. @KRONWALLED

Comment: I've tried all three modules: react-document-meta, react-meta-tags, and react-helmet. The first appears to have been abandoned. The second does not support React 18 and maybe even 17. That left react-helmet. The first and last both have issues with deprecated component mount routines that are logged in the browser console.

Answer (score 45):

You almost definitely want to use:

## [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet)

In contrast to `react-meta-tags` it can nest `<Helmet>`s and so you can define your meta tags deep within your app - like `<title>`s that should override each other. And in contrast to `react-document-meta` you can define things using jsx (and nest things).

This seems to be the solution that the community almost exclusively uses - 600,000 weekly downloads vs the 6,000 given in other solutions. "Helmet takes plain HTML tags and outputs plain HTML tags. It's dead simple, and React beginner friendly." - and has support for server-side rendering.

Here's an example, adapted from the front page:

```
<Parent>
    I'm a parent
    <Helmet>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Helmet application" />
    </Helmet>
 
    <Child>
        I'm a child
        <Helmet>
            <title>Nested Title</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Nested component" />
        </Helmet>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

outputs:

```
<head>
    <title>Nested Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Nested component">
</head>
<Parent>
    I'm a parent
    <Child>
        I'm a child
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Helmet is great. Your argument is *ad populum*, however, and you haven't shown any code.

Comment: will react helment make my page to index on google since I have added meta tags and description?

Comment: where should i add this in my React component?

Comment: It hasn't been updated since 3 years. Is it still relevant?

Comment: @FTW , i thought the same but then it has around 2 MILLION weekly downloads so im guessing the package just maxed out and is too good to be upgraded

Answer (score 42):

You can use [react-meta-tags](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-meta-tags). It allows you to write title and other meta tags in a declarative way and in normal jsx format, which will be moved to head (Check server usage on the doc).

```
import React from 'react';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

class Component1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div class="wrapper">
          <MetaTags>
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <meta id="meta-description" name="description" content="Some description." />
            <meta id="og-title" property="og:title" content="MyApp" />
            <meta id="og-image" property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg" />
          </MetaTags>
          <div class="content"> Some Content </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

You may also like to check [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) if you have an advanced use case.

Comment: I had an issue with duplicate metatags while trying to use react-meta-tags. [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) did **not** duplicate tags on route or state change.

Comment: This has been fixed now.

Comment: @SudhanshuYadav Still not fixed. Just tried `og:title` and `og:image`

Comment: @SudhanshuYadav i know been a long time since this post, but I am facing this issue, I see meta tags when I inspect element, but it doesn't show on page source. Is there any way We can generate dynamic tags and show them in page source.

Comment: Not clear if it supports things like header tags which is important for SEO.

Answer (score 19):

You cand also give the page title and meta tags description  in the following way.

place a meta tag of description in your index.html file like this.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title>Dynamic Page title here</title>
```

in your .js files or .jsx files below the render() method write the page title and meta description for the page like this .

```
render()
{
document.title ="Welcome | here is your page title to display"; 
document.getElementsByTagName("META")[2].content="Your description about the page or site here to set dynamically";

return(
    <div>Page content</div>
);
}
```

Comment: I can see my meta tags being updated using this approach, but when I use twitter card validator or facebook share debugger, it doesn't find my meta/opengraph tags :( Note : I am static hosting

Comment: Or you can just use `getElementsByName` to be more specific by targeting by the element's name

Comment: This is not going to work. Because document is a javascript code and search crawler cant read javascript

Comment: Just a small tip that worked for me (working in SSR architecture. I put this on the componentDidMount() method.

Comment: For some reason, the meta tags end up in the html body instead of the head

Answer (score 11):

Firstly if you don't need dynamic data you can just edit `public/index.html`.

For dynamic data the React team [recommends](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/) to either use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>React app</title>
                <meta name="description" content="React application" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Or using placeholders and [replacing them server-side](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/#injecting-data-from-the-server-into-the-page):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="__OG_TITLE__" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="__OG_DESCRIPTION__" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the method how to replacing them on server-side

Comment: Via the first link: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/#injecting-data-from-the-server-into-the-page

Answer (score 6):

According to the official documentation [React Doc - Title and Meta Tags](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/title-and-meta-tags), you can also use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

Comment: This library is quite behind. They use deprecated lifecycle hooks...

Comment: @mmla at the time of that comment, Hooks were introduced only two (!) months prior...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the document query and update their values.

```
const setTitle = title => {
    const el = document.querySelector('title');
    el.innerText = `${el.text} | ${title}`;
  };

const setDescription = desc => {
    const el = document.querySelector("meta[name='description']");
    el.setAttribute('content',desc)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**As `create-react-app` [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/#changing-the-title-tag) mentioned:**

> If you need to dynamically update the page title based on the content, you can use the browser [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) API. For more complex scenarios when you want to change the title from React components, you can use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet), a third party library.

A simple example:

```js
function App(){
  document.title = "Home";
  return (
   <div>...</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but @Fahd Allebdi's solution did.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late but you can do this very simply like this:

Just use `useEffect()` in your component like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.head.innerHTML+=`
  <meta name='description' content='My description value!!!'/>
  <meta name='keywords' content='My keywords!!!'/>
  `
}, []);
```

Comment: This will append to the innerHTML every time the useEffect is called. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

https://react.dev/blog/2023/03/22/react-labs-what-we-have-been-working-on-march-2023#document-metadata

there will be no need for external tools.

> "This is why we’re adding built-in support for rendering ,
> , and metadata  tags anywhere in your component tree out
> of the box. It would work the same way in all environments, including
> fully client-side code, SSR, and in the future, RSC. We will share
> more details about this soon."

Comment: Example of implementation of it?

Answer (score 0):

I will supplement the answers for React with Vite projects, property="og:image".
Maybe it will be useful to someone)

1. place the image in the root folder /public
2. in index.html add:

   `<meta property="og:image" content="https://yourWebSite.net/yourImage.png" />`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is the answer you were looking for but I was searching for how to update the info your react app shows when you preview the link in some other app. Every solution I tried wasn't working with github pages and react (react-helmet, react-meta-tags, react-document-meta). What ended up working was that you can edit the `index.html` located inside the `public` folder to change this info. Include this somewhere in the head:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/IMDB.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>IMDB</title>
    <meta property="og:audio" content="http://example.com/bond/theme.mp3" />
    <meta property="og:description" 
      content="Sean Connery found fame and fortune as the
               suave, sophisticated British agent, James Bond." />
    <meta property="og:determiner" content="the" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/bond/trailer.swf" />
```

Example from https://ogp.me/

Comment: Man that's like shitting on reactjs anyway upvote cuz it's not so bad after all

Answer (score -1):

You can use querySelector to access the tags and change the attribute value from it.

```
useEffect(()=>{
document.title="Page Title"
let descMeta=document.querySelector("meta[name='description']")
descMeta.setAttribute("content", 'Description of your page')
let themeMeta=document.querySelector("meta[name='theme-color']")
themeMeta.setAttribute("content", "#ffffff")
},[])
```

This is one way you can change the title and other tags from head.