# Dynamic Meta Tag In React Js Without Ssr , Without Using Helmet Tag and only Front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a one problem,in my project i can't use ***SSR,Helmet*** and ***back-end***, ***Is that possible we can use dynamic meta without using SSR and Back-end***, if we can use only react js in front end,and ***i have alreay try react helment but it's not work in my project***,becouse my project is size very big,so if eny solution please give me answer....

i have alreay try many solutions and react library but no any one working like... ***helmet,react-helmet,react-helmet-async,react-meta-tags,react-meta***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update meta tags in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734150/how-to-update-meta-tags-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you trying to achieve. The concept divides into two choices. Server side or client side.

If client side you should be comfortable with *react-helmet*. You mentioned that your project is so big. I don't think this is anything related to project size to change meta dynamically. What I think about why you can't accomplish react-helmet is you didn't remove static *meta* codes from your **index.html**. What happening is you might are getting client side dynamic meta that is generated from helmet but being replaced by already static meta tags from **index.html**. So remove them and it should work fine...

Now come to dynamic *SEO* for **OG (Open Graph)** Meta Tags without **SSR**. There are few packages that pre render dynamic meta tags that might help to solve your problems without **SSR** implemented on your *React App*.

- [react-snap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap) is the solution you are looking for.
- Look at       **[THIS](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/213)** discussion.
- [Strategies to SEO on React](https://medium.com/mixed-marketing-technology/our-solution-to-make-seo-work-for-a-react-js-site-rankwatch-blog-9a311b86fb5f)
- [Using Express as backend](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/)

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using below procedure and it worked well for me ,

Write your PHP code for take only meta tags based on url slug at top of file in react js public/index.html

```
 <?php
    
    $url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $meta = [];
    $meta = json_decode(file_get_contents('api_url'));

    
    //Add your API call by using file_get_contents or curl to take meta tags  value from backend
    
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    -----
    -----
    ---
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $meta['title'];?>" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $meta['description'];?>" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $meta['url'];?>" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $meta['cover_image'];?>" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

Then create .htaccess file where your index.html falls in server and write below code in .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Then update package.json like below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && sudo mv index.html index.php",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Now it will get worked