# Is it possible to change meta tags dynamically while page is loading

Tags: html, reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

Here is the case. In my React(SPA) application I have only one page that needs to be shared. And when it is shared I need to add the following meta tags to the head element:

```
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="some text" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="../../some-ing.png" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="some text"  />
</head>
```

All content for meta tags is dynamic. I tried to use react-helmet-async library. It changes the meta tags when the page mounts if I check it in the developer tools, but when I share the link to this page the image and description is not shown with a link.

Is it possible to implement it without SSR?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497519/dynamic-meta-tag-in-react-js-without-ssr-without-using-helmet-tag-and-only-fro

Comment: @Chinz thank you for your reply. I checked it. The first option they recommend is a library (react-snap), that was last published 5 years ago( Have you ever used it? Other options require Express or Next...

Comment: I haven't used it myself yet.